# High latency w Scarlet Solo 2nd Gen

Tags: audio, usb, dac

When playing audio through my scarlet solo, the audio latency goes quite high every few minutes, sometimes for around 10 seconds.
[image: LatencyMon reporting high latency]

My system plays audio fine through other outputs, it only happens with usb devices.
[image: Settings]

Comment: As noted in the diagnostic report, your buffer is too small.